# How can I update the stable toolchain when I get the error "some components unavailable for target i386-apple-ios/armv7s-apple-ios"?

Tags: rust, rustup

I try to run

```
rustup update stable
```

and I get the following output.

```
info: syncing channel updates for 'stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu'
info: latest update on 2020-05-07, rust version 1.43.1 (8d69840ab 2020-05-04)
error: some components unavailable for download for channel stable: 'rust-std' for target 'i386-apple-ios', 'rust-std' for target 'armv7s-apple-ios', 'rust-std' for target 'armv7-apple-ios'
If you require these components, please install and use the latest successful build version,
which you can find at <https://rust-lang.github.io/rustup-components-history>.

After determining the correct date, install it with a command such as:

    rustup toolchain install nightly-2018-12-27

Then you can use the toolchain with commands such as:

    cargo +nightly-2018-12-27 build
```

While I can install the latest stable toolchain using

```
rustup toolchain install stable-2020-05-07
```

That creates a separate toolchain.

```
rustup toolchain list
stable-2020-05-07-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu (default)
stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
nightly-2020-05-07-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
```

I can use this new toolchain as the default (as I am now), but it's going to be a pain moving forward as I can't just use `rustup update`.

Running `rustup toolchain install stable` yields the same error.

How can I get the stable Rust toolchain to update via `rustup update run`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> The Rust team regrets to announce that Rust 1.41.0 (to be released on January 30th, 2020) will be the last release with the current level of support for 32-bit Apple targets. Starting from Rust 1.42.0, those targets will be demoted to Tier 3.
>
> [Reducing support for 32-bit Apple targets](https://blog.rust-lang.org/2020/01/03/reducing-support-for-32-bit-apple-targets.html)

You will need to remove those components using `rustup component remove`. I can't test the exact invocation, but something like:

```
rustup component remove --toolchain stable --target i386-apple-ios rust-std
rustup component remove --toolchain stable --target armv7s-apple-ios rust-std
rustup component remove --toolchain stable --target armv7-apple-ios rust-std
```

Once removed, you can update your compiler.